# Iteration matrix representation with complex conjugate operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

I am studying the convergence of a particular class of radial power flows, whose goal is to obtain the voltage solution for a given electric grid, i.e., a complex vector $\mathbf{V}$ that gives the voltage for each node.

The radial power flow can be expressed as an iterative procedure, with one step given by
$$\begin{equation}
\mathbf{V}^{(k)} = M\mathbf{V^{*}}^{(k-1)} + V_0 \mathbf{1},
\end{equation}
$$

where $M$ is a matrix that captures the grid properties (line resistances, topology, ...), and $*$ denotes the complex conjugate.

If there was no complex conjugate, I would compute the maximum value of the eigenvalues of $M$ to check for convergence. However, in this case since the complex conjugate cannot be specified as a linear transformation, is this convergence check still valid?

Comment: can you be more precise what you mean by $M(V)^\ast$ ? for example, by writing this in components?

Comment: $M$ is a linear transformation that acts on the vector $V^*$.
In fact the notation can be misleading, the parenthesis are there only to indicate that $V^{(k-1)}$ is the complex conjugate

Comment: The $M$ matrix is a standard linear operator. Different grid configurations return different $M$'s, so I want to check, for a given grid, the convergence of the iterative radial power flow. However, the doubt that I presented (the way to deal with the complex conjugate on V) prevents me from doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\V{\mathbf V}\newcommand\1{\mathbf 1}\newcommand\0{\mathbf 0}$You can just rewrite your iteration in the real form, as
$$\begin{bmatrix}V_1^k\\V_2^k \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}M_1&M_2\\M_2&-M_1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}V_1^{k-1}\\V_2^{k-1} \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\Re V_0\1\\ \Im V_0\1 \end{bmatrix},$$
where $V_1^k:=\Re\V^{(k)}$,  $V_2^k:=\Im\V^{(k)}$,  $M_1:=\Re M$, $M_2:=\Im M$.